Bottom bar icon doesn't show the right page
I am currently working on the bottom bar navigation and I added another icon button next to the saved icon, that should redirect the user to Bookings page, but instead of doing that, it redirected me to the page of 'Share' Here it's the code and here its a video of the check issue https://imgur.com/a/Qi5lc85
Widget _bottomBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      elevation: 4.0,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: (index) async {
        setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
        _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        if (index == 5) {
          count = 0;
          final currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Users')
              .doc(currentUserId)
              .update({'newChat': false});
        }
      },
      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Home',
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Saved',
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite_border,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite_border,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Bookings',
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.calendar_month_rounded,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.calendar_month,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        const BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Share',
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.share_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.share_outlined,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: 'Messages',
          icon: Flexible(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.send,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('Users')
                        .doc(userId)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      return Positioned(
                        right: 0,
                        child: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<
                                    Map<String, dynamic>>)['newChat'] !=
                                null
                            ? (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot<
                                    Map<String, dynamic>>)['newChat']
                                ? const CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 4,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                  )
                                : const SizedBox()
                            : const SizedBox(),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
class Appbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const Appbar({super.key});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
        offset: const Offset(0.0, -10),
        child: Container(
            height: 50,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(80),
              ),
              child: BottomAppBar(
                color: Colors.white24,
                elevation: 200,
                shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                notchMargin: 20.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => FavoriteProviders()));
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_month,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => BookingOrdersScreen()));
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CustomerPosts()));
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                      ),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MessageList()));
//                Navigator.push(
//                  context,
//                  MaterialPageRoute(
//                      builder: (context) => StoryScreen(stories: stories)),
//                );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),


As per your bottom navigation you have added 5 index/icons can you tell me you have add 5 different pages for each?

yes , I added more to the code
